# .Htaccess Redirect Rule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

Need help with an 301 htaccess redirect rule doing the following for all the files in these paths:
I want to redirct this URLs http://www.example.org/archives/xxxxx to http://www.example.org/?=xxxxx

Have to remove /archives and add ?= to URL with random numbers got form old URLs.

(xxxxx is random number )

Really appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for your answer Starkeen but it's not working.
I got the solution. Please add the following rule to your `.htaccess` file.

`RewriteRule ^archives\/(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.example.com\.com\/?p=$1" [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Redirect in your htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/archives/(.*)$ http://example.org/?=$1
```